# Add Worksheet name to first six rows

Tags: vba, loops, insert, worksheet

I have a large numbers of worksheets in a Workbook.

I want to insert a new row at the top of each worksheet (A:A) and insert the name of each worksheet into cells (B1:G1) for all worksheets.

I have the first portion, but am a little stuck on the second part (i.e., adding the worksheet name). I would appreciate some help.

Corrected CODE:

```
Sub NameSheets()
Dim sheetnm() As String
ReDim sheetnm(1 To Sheets.Count)
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        sheetnm(i) = Sheets(i).Name
        Sheets(i).Range("B1:G1") = Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Did any of the below work for you?  If so please mark it as correct.  It is something only you can do.  It will close the question as answered and will reward those that take time to help as an incentive to help others and yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Range ("B1:G1") = ActiveSheet.name . This will add the current worksheet name to all 6 columns

Comment: Hi your code was a great starting point. However, it only added the sheet name to whichever shete the user was currently looking at. The updated code above adds a row and name to all sheets within the workbook

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code. Try this:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In Worksheets
    sheet.Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    sheet.Range("B1:G1").Value = sheet.Name
Next sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cycle through the sheets twice.  The first to add the first row and create an array of the sheet names.  The second to input that list in the first row starting in B1:

```
Sub NameSheets()
Dim sheetnm() As String
ReDim sheetnm(1 To Sheets.Count)
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    sheetnm(i) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Range("B1").Resize(, UBound(sheetnm)).Value = sheetnm
Next ws

End Sub
```